# Is it possible to restrict the arguments for a function to a specific entity type?

Tags: function-construction, entity, data-types

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to work with Mathematica for building (computable) domain specific knowledge. One particular thing I didn't quite understand is how to create symbols for operations which are to be applied (computed) only for specific [entity-types](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html). I understand how I can restrict the pattern-matching to basic datatypes (i.e using `x_Integer` as parameter to restrict input to only integers for example). But all entities share the exact same head (`Entity`), so how do I make the pattern understand which specific entity-type I want to match on?

ex:

```
f[x_{Planet entity}]:=y
```

which I'd like to evaluate to `y` if, for example, `x="Entity["Planet", "Mercury"]"`, but not if `Entity["Country", "Sweden"]`

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a specific function that'll check for entity-types, but maybe you can just use `PatternTest` or `Condition` to check if it's the 'correct' type of entity. Something like `f[x_?MemberQ[EntityList["Planet"],#]&]`?

Comment: `x : HoldPattern[Entity["Planet", __]]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out by Kuba in comments, when we make a function definition the pattern variables are not restricted to be simple `x_head`.  So you can create a definition like

```
f[ent:HoldPattern[Entity["Planet", planetName_]]] := <do something>
```

The `HoldPattern` is only needed if you want to make the definition but avoid evaluation or package autoloading. Since `Entity[ "Planet", planetName_]` doesn't actually evaluate, here it is used to avoid autoloading the entity framework when making the definition.

The above definition would fire for even invalid planet entities - it would work with `Entity["Planet", "Bob"]` for example.  You could go further with your definition, and restrict it to only valid entities, if only there were a `ValidEntityQ` function.  Evaluating `` ?EntityFramework`* `` we see there is a function `` EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ `` that seems like what we want.  It is an undocumented function, so it could stop working at some point in the future, but it seems to be present in every version of the entity framework I have available to me now and it isn't a `` Private` `` function so I would think it relatively safe to use.

So you could make your definition like

```
f[ent:HoldPattern[Entity["Planet", planetName_]]] /; 
      EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ[ent] := <do something>

f[ent___] := $Failed
```

to make it only fire for valid planet entities.

Comment: But there is a Planet Bob: http://cybernations.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Bob :)

Comment: Nice, one follow-up question only; are there any performance considerations regarding this pattern?

Comment: @Whil These guards are usually fairly safe to use and the performance seems fine. I was about to write an answer in line of the one above but it is already perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`EntityTypeName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityTypeName.html) (from 2014) so one could do :

```
g[x_] /; EntityTypeName[x] === "Planet" := x["Mass"]
```

Check :

```
g[Entity["Planet", "Mars"]]
```

`(* Quantity[6.417*10^23, "Kilograms"] *)`

```
g[Entity["Species", "Species:FelisCatus"]]
```

`(* g[Entity["Species", "Species:FelisCatus"]] *)`

```
g[42]
```

[image]

`(* g[42] *)`